# Create WPF forms dynamically using XAML files

Tags: wpf-controls

I am trying to write a program to dynamically create WPF forms. Is it possible to create XAML file and make .NET framework load them automatically?

I don't know if this is a really dumb question, but I was wondering that it might save me the burden of writing code to create them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx) can do this very easily.

```
var stream = File.OpenRead(xamlFileName);
//cast to whatever is the toplevel element in XAML
var loadedElement = (Window)XamlReader.Load(stream);
```

There is also [a lot of resources on this subject](http://www.google.com/search?q=dynamically+load+xaml) on the web.